# Remove dates which are outside of specific range in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

Hello:) I have following dataset with format 'datatime64'. My intention is to delete all rows that are not from year 2014 and 2015. How should I do it using pandas library?:)

```
1       2014-08-11
2       2014-07-08
3       2014-09-02
4       2015-04-23
           ...    
21615   2015-01-07
21616   2014-06-17
21617   2015-04-17
21618   2014-08-20
21619   2015-03-19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is already formated as a datetime object you can just apply simple filtering like

```
df[~df.date.dt.year.isin([2014,2015])]
```

or apply a filter to exclude time ranges

`df[(df.date < "2014-01-01") | (df.date > "2016-01-01)]`

If its not datetime already you can use `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` to convert your column